# Overriding struct data layout

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am currently writing a small GUI toolkit frontend in ANSI C and define a default struct for colors. But since the color struct layout depends on the backend I wanted to have the possibility to override the layout and tried to use the preprocessor to define the layout in the GUI header file:

```
#ifndef GUI_OVERRIDE_COLOR_LAYOUT
  struct gui_color {unsigned long rgb;};
#else
  GUI_OVERRIDE_COLOR_LAYOUT
#endif
```

But when I try to override the color struct layout before I include the header in a source file I get two different versions. One for the frontend and one for the backend and get completely wrong data out of the structure.

```
#define GUI_OVERRIDE_COLOR_LAYOUT\
  struct gui_color {float r,g,b,a;};
#include "gui.h"
```

It is important to note that the frontend does not access the color struct directly but instead just forwards the colors to the backend by address.
So is it even possible to use the preprocessor to override the layout of a struct or am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Comment: The frontend only deals with pointers? Wouldn't a simple forward declaration do the job?

Comment: Just do not do that macro evil (In this case the two POD structures have different sizes)

Comment: The frontend has an array of colors, selects a color based on the widget to draw and calls a callback with the address of the color. So the frontend still needs to know the layout of the color struct.

Comment: Please provide more context. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve